# changing display depending on fields value

Tags: views, theming

I want to change how a field value can be displayed to the front-end user,

For example I have an Article content type which have a priority fields,
this priority can be either low or high as a value...

so I want when the priorty is high, my displayed view show me an image icon instead of the high value.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use `MY_THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables)` in template.php and build your logic according to $variables array elements (e.g. $variables['field_priority']). Example:

```
function MY_THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if($variables['type'] == 'page') {
    $priority = $variables['field_priority'];

    if($priority > 0 && $priority < 2) {
      // do_first_logic()
    }
    elseif($priority > 2 && $priority < 4) {
      // do_second_logic()
    }
    // .... so on
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Field conditional state](https://drupal.org/project/field-conditional-state) module.

> With field conditional state module you can set #state form field
>   attribute based on value selected in other form fields. Module splits
>   fields into two types:

- control field - field which set #state attribute based on the value from that field,
- controled field - field for which #state attribute is set based on the value from the control field.

(or)

You can try [Conditional Fields](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module which ability to modify fields appearance and behavior on certain conditions when viewing content.